# "message": "Method Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard::factory does not exist.",

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I am trying to add JWT using `"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"` to `Laravel Framework 7.26.1`. Have setup everything as per document. https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/

This is my AuthController.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    
    class AuthController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Create a new AuthController instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
        }
    
        /**
         * Get a JWT via given credentials.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function login()
        {
    
            $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    
            if (! $token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
            }
    
            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }
...
```

this is api.php

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->middleware('api');

Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
```

when trying to hit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/`from postman, this is what i am getting

```
{
"message": "Method Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard::factory does not exist.",
"exception": "BadMethodCallException",
"file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php",
"line": 103,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php",
        "line": 307,
        "function": "__call",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php",
        "line": 81,
        "function": "__call",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php",
        "line": 34,
        "function": "respondWithToken",
        "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "function": "login",
        "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
        "line": 54,
        "function": "call_user_func_array"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
        "line": 45,
        "function": "callAction",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
        "line": 239,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
        "line": 196,
        "function": "runController",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 685,
        "function": "run",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 128,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
        "line": 41,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php",
        "line": 59,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 687,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 662,
        "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 628,
        "function": "runRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 617,
        "function": "dispatchToRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 165,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 128,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
        "line": 27,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
        "line": 63,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 140,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 109,
        "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/public/index.php",
        "line": 55,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laraval-certificate/arc.dev/server.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "require_once"
    }
]
```

}

to me it seems like it's trying to using web guard which i don't understand since i am hitting routes in api.php. anyone what mistake i am making ?

Comment: Okay, this fixed it. 
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1484

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay. So apparently you have to specify guard in expires_in `'expires_in' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60`

I updated `respondWithToken` Function of `AuthController.php` to

```
return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        //'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        'expires_in' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60
    ]);
```

and it fixed it.

Answer (score 19):

Correct but since you are dealing with an API, you could have changed your default guard from `web` to `api` in `config/auth.php` as per below:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Then you can use auth without specifying the guard:
`'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60`

You may also need to run `php artisan optimize` to clear cache and all should be good.

Answer (score 4):

If you are implementing this for a graphql app,make sure to include this in your `config/auth.php`

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

and also don't forget to implement `implements JWTSubject` in User.php model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{ use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

 public function getJWTIdentifier () {
    return $this->getKey();
 }

 public function getJWTCustomClaims () {
    return [];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling the package  , for example "composer require tymon/jwt-auth"
or just composer dump-autoload to reorder the libs